# Why does jQuery.html() successfully accepts a jQuery object even though the docs says it can't?

Tags: jquery

I am just trying to understand exactly how this works because I have a bug in my code that might be related to my misunderstanding.

The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) say the `htmlString` parameter of `.html(htmlString)` can be either an `htmlString` or a `function`, yet if I do this

```
var $div = $("div").detach();
$("body").html($div);
```

the detached div `correctly` replaces the body contents even though `$div` is a jQuery object.

For completeness' sake my full code is below

```
<html>
<body style="font-size:25px">

<div><p> CLICK TO TEST </p></div>

<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("p").click(function() { console.log("P1 CLICKED!"); });

    var $div = $("div").detach();

    $("body").html($div);
    //$("body").html($div);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: That question should be asked to the jQuery team, not some random internet people helping other random internet people ahah! Why does it say it has to be a string or a function? That, we don't have the answer.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Thanks for your comment, but Stack Overflow is a Wiki meaning once the question is asked and answered someone else can find it quickly without having to ask again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, we can't answer your direct question since we aren't the one writing the doc, but I can show you why it work.

As you can see on [this line](https://gist.github.com/kagagnon/a13de27760ba1af883c0#file-gistfile1-js-L6150), jQuery check if the passed value is a string. If it is, it does some replace to make a valid HTML then, [the `if` close](https://gist.github.com/kagagnon/a13de27760ba1af883c0#file-gistfile1-js-L6171).

So no matter what you pass as argument, [it run those lines](https://gist.github.com/kagagnon/a13de27760ba1af883c0#file-gistfile1-js-L6173) :

```
if ( elem ) {
    this.empty().append( value );
}
```

As you know, `.append()` accept a string, DOM element or jQuery object. Hence, that is why it is working. `.html` doesnt *really* check if the argument is a string.

Comment: Thanks for your time. What I learned is that sometimes you have to read the source. :)

Answer (score 2):

In short if not a string or function it forwards the passed argument to `jQuery.fn.append` which accepts DOM or Jquery objects [.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) Which is why your code works.

Here is a minified version of the function for clarity.

```
html: function( value ) {
    if ( value === undefined ) {
    ...
    } else if ( typeof value === "string" && ..... ) {
    ...
    } else if ( jQuery.isFunction( value ) ) {
    ...
    } else {
        this.empty().append( value );
    }

    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because the jquery object extends the JQuery function which acts as a prototype for the '$' object. So it's recognizable as a function. Plus, every javascript object "is" a function

Comment: I've heard *"every function is a javascript object"*, but *"every javascript object is a function"* is new to me...?

Comment: `var x = $('<div>'); x();` You will get an error: object is not a function

Comment: Thanks, but the required function must return a string according to the docs and surely the jQuery object does not?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon sorry, I mispelled that part. I meant js function is a _function_ object