# Why does the second call to .html() stop the click() function from working?

Tags: jquery, dom

I have asked a somewhat related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403411/why-does-jquery-html-successfully-accepts-a-jquery-object-even-though-the-docs). I have the following simple HTML and jQuery code

```
<html>
<body style="font-size:25px">

<div><p> CLICK TO TEST </p></div>

<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("p").click(function() { console.log("P1 CLICKED!"); });

    var $div = $("div").detach();

    $("body").html($div);
    //$("body").html($div); // If I uncomment this the click event stops firing!!
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the above code, if I uncomment the line which calls `.html()` again, the click event stops firing, but I thought the `$div` jQuery object would simply replace the `body` content again without losing its click event.

How can this be explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403411/why-does-jquery-html-successfully-accepts-a-jquery-object-even-though-the-docs), no matter what you pass to `html`, those lines will run :

```
if ( elem ) {
    this.empty().append( value );
}
```

Now, it is important to know that [`.empty` clear the data of the element](https://gist.github.com/kagagnon/a13de27760ba1af883c0#file-gistfile1-js-L6103). It mean everything stored inside `.data()` and every events are deleted to prevent memory leak.

So, the first time you do `$("body").html($div);`, the `p` is not inside the body since you `.detach`'ed it just before. The `.empty` isn't affecting the `p` and it keep its events. But if you do it 2 times in a row, the element is reattached to the body after the first `.html` and `.empty` is taking effect. It erase its event.

Solution would be to use event delegation, it is easy and don't have to `.detach` anything :

```
$('body').on("click", "p", function() {
  //Your code
});
```

Comment: but the variable still remains the same, if I'm not wrong right?

Comment: Yes, the variable is the same, but cleaned from its datas.

Comment: @Amit @Karl To be clear, are you saying that after I called `html($div)` or `append($div)` the `$div` that is re-attached is still the same object as the `$div` I originally detached, i.e. no cloning? In that case it suddenly makes sense! Instead of event delegation (a superb answer in this case), would it be possible to clone the `$div` when detaching so I can re-attach it as many times as I like?

Comment: @Floris yes, cloning the div would prevent the event from being removed, but since you are using `.html`. it will always `.empty` before adding it. You should do `$('body').empty().append($div.clone(true), $div.clone(true), ...)`;

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Ok, finally working exactly as I want it. Thanks for your help and patience. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could change your event listener to

```
$(document).on("click", "p", function() {
  // whatever
});
```

I will trigger on every `p` element, no matter if they've been add after the page finished loading.